# SSRS Report in chrome --Report is not scrolling Horizontally

Tags: javascript, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We are using `SSRS-2012` and our client needs to view the reports in `chrome`. we added below code in `enter code here`reportingservices.js file

> ```
> function pageLoad() {
>
>  var element = document.getElementById("ctl32_ctl09");
>
>  if (element) {
>
>     element.style.overflow = "visible";
>
>  }
>
>  }
> ```

Now reports are visible in `chrome`. But, there is an issue while we scroll report `horizontally`.  The `parameter section` is also scrolled with the report.  when we move to the end of the report , it looks like below

[image]

this issue occur only `chrome` and the `report` works perfectly in

```
Internet explorer.
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: the parameter panel should be freeze always. in the above image, the space (red arrow) shouldn't be there

Answer (score 1):

It's some time ago I had a similar problem. MS obviously did some updates to IE and / or SSRS 2012 that made some reports near to no longer useable. I was looking which browser could be an alternative (including Chrome). My result was, that Chrome is not well supported, like described here and in the included links: [SSRS problems with Chrome](https://vaidymohan.com/2012/06/26/sql-server-2012-reporting-services-on-safari-chrome-browsers/).

But I had seen, that there is also an Add-On for Chrome that turns tabs into IE like tabs. It's called IE tab. Maybe that can be helpful.